# Proving that ker is $0$ or $ p \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $k$ be a field. Let $\varphi$ be the ring homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb Z \to k $ defined by $\varphi (n.1) = n \varphi (1) = n.1 = n.$ Prove that
$$
\ker(\varphi) = \begin{cases} 
      (0), \\
     p \mathbb Z,   \quad  p \ \rm prime.
\end{cases}$$

Could someone give me a hint of how to tackle this please?

Comment: Do you know the first isomorphism theorem for rings? Remember that the image of $\varphi$ is a subring of the field $k$, hence an integral domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For homomorphisms of rings $f:A\rightarrow B$, where $B$ is an integral domain, the kernel is a prime ideal (this is easy to check). Now, the only prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are $(0)$ and the ideals generated by a prime number (remember that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID).

Comment: Can you give a reference for your first statement please? where can I find its proof?

Comment: @Idonotknow I suppose that every elementary treatise of ring theory mentions it. Anyway, it is a direct consequence of the definition of prime ideal and integral domain.